# How can I check that ALL tags apply to these items in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables: `items` `relationships` `tags` `item_to_tags`. Relationships can connect two items and `items_to_tags` connect tags to items like this:

`items`

| id | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ... |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| 4 | ... |

`relationships`

| source_item_id | target_item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

`tags`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |

`items_to_tags`

| item_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

[The above would give a graph that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d3Bv.png)

I've created a recursive function that will give me all of the descendants starting from a specific item:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_descendants(item_id int)
RETURNS SETOF items AS $$
    WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS (
        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id
        FROM items i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id)
        WHERE i.id = item_id
        UNION

        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id
        FROM descendants a
        JOIN items i ON (a.target_item_id = i.id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id) 
    )

    SELECT * FROM items i WHERE i.id IN (SELECT id FROM descendants WHERE id != item_id);
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

DBFiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/teicDervXhN3AmEPfYzNn2/1

For example, if you run `SELECT * FROM get_items_descendants(1);` then it will return items 3 and 4 since they're the descendants of item 1.

I then updated it to allow a tag filter to be applied like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_descendants(item_id int, tag_filters integer[] = array[]::integer[])
RETURNS SETOF items AS $$
    WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS (
        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id
        FROM items i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id)
        WHERE i.id = item_id
        UNION

        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id
        FROM descendants a
        JOIN items i ON (a.target_item_id = i.id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN items_to_tags t ON (i.id = t.item_id)
        WHERE cardinality(tag_filters::integer[]) = 0 OR t.tag_id = ANY(tag_filters)
    )

    SELECT * FROM items i WHERE i.id IN (SELECT id FROM descendants WHERE id != item_id);
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

DBFiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xvKwN96kJnBqZ59QUXbYvj/1

Now calling `SELECT * FROM get_items_descendants(1, ARRAY[0]);` only returns item 3 because item 4 doesn't have the tag `A`. Passing `ARRAY[0,1]` or `ARRAY[1]` returns both 3 and 4 because they both have tag `B` and the `t.tag_id = ANY(tag_filters)` only requires one of the tag filters to exist.

What i'm struggling with is updating the function so that ALL tags must exist if they're defined in the tag_filters parameter. So `ARRAY[0,1]` will only return item 3.

Is this possible? The data structure above is fairly locked so can't be changed too much as it's already in production. Also, if anyone has any advice on the functions above that would be much appreciated as i'm quite new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to do a solution for when none of the tags apply as well as any of and all of. This is my current solution if anyone finds it useful. If anyone has any ways of improving it then please let me know:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_descendants(item_id int, tag_filters integer[] = array[]::integer[], operation text = 'any')
RETURNS SETOF items AS $$
    WITH RECURSIVE descendants AS (
        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id, -1 as tag_id
        FROM items i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id)
        WHERE i.id = item_id
        UNION

        SELECT i.id, r.target_item_id, t.tag_id
        FROM descendants d
        JOIN items i ON (d.target_item_id = i.id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN relationships r ON (i.id = r.source_item_id) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN items_to_tags t ON (i.id = t.item_id)
        WHERE (operation = 'none' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM items_to_tags WHERE item_id = i.id AND tag_id = ANY(tag_filters)))
            OR (operation != 'none' AND (cardinality(tag_filters::integer[]) = 0 OR t.tag_id = ANY(tag_filters)))
    )

    SELECT * FROM items i 
        WHERE (operation = 'all'
            AND i.id IN (
                SELECT id FROM (
                    SELECT id, array_agg(tag_id) as tag_ids
                    FROM descendants d
                    WHERE id != item_id
                    GROUP BY id
                ) as d
                WHERE d.tag_ids @> tag_filters
            )
        )
        OR (operation != 'all'
            AND i.id IN (
                SELECT id FROM descendants WHERE id != item_id
            )
        );
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```